# How to Display a Gridview inside jquery dialog by clicking a link button inside another gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview showing columns BusRoute,BusNo and Action.Where action contains the linkbuttons to display another gridview.I want to display it in jquery dialog.My codes are.

ASPX Code:

First Gridview:

```
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" OnClientClick="showDialog();">Shipment Status</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                   </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Second Gridview:

```
            <div class="gridview_stop"  id="popup">
                <asp:GridView ID="Stops" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="6" Width="190px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bus Stop" DataField="StopName" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#006B89">
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006B89" Font-Size="18px" Font-Bold="false"></HeaderStyle>
                            <ItemStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

Code Behind File:

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetRoutes", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusStop1", Source.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusStop2", Destination.Text);
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    adapter.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Route.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Route.DataBind();
        Stops.DataSource = null;
        Stops.DataBind();
        Lblmsg.Text = "";
    }
    else
    Lblmsg.Text = "No Direct Bus Between These Stop";
    Lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    Route.Dispose();
    Route.DataBind();
    Stops.Dispose();
    Stops.DataBind();
}
protected void Route_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='aquamarine';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.backgroundColor='white';";
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click last column for selecting this row.";
    }
}


protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = Route.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

    SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();

    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    string connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BusService;uid=sa;Password=Murli@925";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStops", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   int BusNo= Convert.ToInt32(Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusNo",BusNo);

    adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter1.Fill(ds1);
    adapter1.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    Stops.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
    Stops.DataBind();
}
```

Jquery Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#lnkbtn").live("click",
         function showDialog() {

             $("#popup").dialog({
                 show: { effect: "fold", duration: 4000 },
                 hide: { effect: "fold", duration: 4000 },

             });
             return false;

         });

        $(document).click(function (event) {
            if (!$(event.target).closest('#popup').length) {
                if ($('#popup').is(":visible")) {
                    $('#popup').dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })

</script>
```

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at your rendered html when you run the page.  Unless you set `ClientIDMode` to *Static* I doubt that your button ID's are `$("#lnkbtn")` but more like `$("#gvWhatever_lnkbtn_0")`
2. Set `OnClientClick="showDialog();"` *or* `$("#lnkbtn").live("click", function showDialog(){...})` no need to do both.
3. Using a Server Control button to activate a popup usually doesn't work.  Especially if GridView Row Selection is enabled.  I can't tell if your first GridView has that feature enabled as I only see a portion of the listing.  But what tends to happen is you trigger a postback while trying to display the popup so you never see the popup.
4. Also your second popup contains a gridview, which requires a databind.  so you need to make sure the gridview is populated with the data before activating the popup

### Two methods for showing a popup using jquery from within a Gridview:

**A portion of a GridView markup with 2 TemplateField's**

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
          <div class="rs-icon rs-icon-info tooltip-marker" role="button">
          </div>
          <div id="ContactInfo" style="display:none;">
            <table id="tblContactDetail" class="ContactDetail Note">
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 80px">Name</td>
                <td style="width: 100%">
                  <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" 
                       Text='<%# Eval("expert_name") %>' />
                </td>
              </tr>
              .
              .
              .
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      <ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CV">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divButtonViewCV" runat="server" 
             class="rs-icon rs-icon-cv" role="button" 
             onclick='<%# Eval("expert_cv_id", "ViewPDF({0})") %>' >
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In the above markup I'm setting up for two styles of "popup".  The first Template uses [jQueryUI ToolTip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) which is activated on mouseover/out.  This is nice because it doesn't require a click which means no worries about a postback mucking up the works.  The interesting thing here is that I'm using a `div` as button.

**How it works:** The div with the *.tooptip-marker* class is set up to activate a jqueryui tooltip which will display the contents of `<div id="ContentInfo">` by grabbing the inner html of the sibling div of the activating button. Note that this div is styled as *display:none;* so that the content is available for the tooltip but hidden so the main GridView displays as normal.

For brevity, I included only a portion of the content of `<div id="ContentInfo">`.  But It can contain anything really.  In my code it's a simple `<table>` containing contact information fields (using bound `<asp:Literal>` controls) that are part of the primary GridView data source.

But this could just have easily been an embedded GridView with it's own data source that is bound in the `OnRowDatabound` event of the primary GridView.

The following jquery sets up the widget.  See [jQueryUI ToolTip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for more complete documentation

```
    $( function() {
        $( document ).tooltip( {
            items: ".tooltip-marker",
            content: function() {
                return $( this ).next().html();
            },
            position: {
                my: "left top",
                at: "right+5 top-5"
            }
        } )
    } );
```

The second Template field is used to activate a popup.  This is where you have to be careful about postbacks.  Again I use a `<div>` styled as an icon and treated as a simple button because I've added `onclick`.

Clicking this button displays a popup so you can view a persons CV in PDF format.  The PDF is stored in our database as a varbinary. Here I use another jquery addon, ([colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)), to display the PDF as a popup over the page.

In the `ViewPDF()` function below note that we prevent the "bubbling up" of the click event to the GridView by setting `cancelBubble = true` (for older IE) or a call to stopPropagation() (all other browsers).

In this code, colorbox sets up an `iframe` and passes the *href* parameter to its `src` attribute.  I'm making a call to an *.ashx* page which is an asp Generic Handler which allows us to serve up other type of content without standard web page overhead.  This could just as easily been configured to accept a standalone *.aspx* page where you could maybe place your secondary grid.

```
    // This plain object is used by the call to colorbox(), please 
    // refer to colorbox documentation for details.
    var colorboxDataExpertCV = {
        height: "85%",
        width: 900,
        opacity: .30,
        fixed: true,
        iframe: true,
        returnFocus: false,
        href: ''
    }

    // ========================================================
    // In the Template above, the onclick code:
    //    onclick='<%# Eval("expert_cv_id", "ViewPDF({0})") %>'
    //
    // Renders to: 
    //    onclick="ViewPDF(12345)"
    //
    //  PdfHandlerExpertsCV.ashx is an GenericHandler that retrieves
    //    the CV from our database and writes the byte array to the 
    //    colorbox iframe as an "application/pdf" content type which 
    //    triggers native browser pdf management either by internal 
    //    viewer or installed PDF plugin
    // ========================================================
    function ViewPDF( p ) {
        if ( event.stopPropagation )
            event.stopPropagation();
        else
            event.cancelBubble = true;

        if ( p && p > 0 ) {
            colorboxDataExpertCV.href = "/PdfHandlerExpertsCV.ashx?cvid=" + p;
            $.colorbox( colorboxDataExpertCV );
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Addendum**

> Let me make it more clear, I need to bind the data in 2nd Gridview and
>   display this Gridview2 in Jquery dialog .This data will be binded and
>   displayed in dialog from on the click event of linkbutton inside
>   Gridview1

As I said above, you cannot bind a GridView (server side event) and then popup a jquery ui dialog (client side event) without introducing much more complexity.  You have to make sure all the data you need for the popup is available by the time you're ready to hit the button that opens the dialog.

The simplest way to accomplish this is to embed GridView2 within GridView1 and take care of the binding all at once.  It's not pretty or efficient and, depending on the number of items shown in each, can slow down the page.  But if you have only a few lines for each it should be acceptable.

1. Embed `GridView2` and `DataSource2` in the `<ItemTemplate>` of a `<TemplateField>` of `GridView1`.
2. Bind `GridView2` in the `RowDataBound` event of `Gridview1` using an appropriate row field or datakey field from `GridView1` and then calling `GridView2.DataBind()`.
3. Add a  element to the same TemplateField
4. Refer to the [jquery dialog modal form example](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) which shows how to trigger a dialog from a button click.  In your case substitute the second GridView for the Form in the example.

**IMPORTANT** be mindful that gridview row item id's get "mangled" so you should not use id's in the jquery calls but use jquery selectors that are based on element name plus class markers, ie: `$("button.marker")` for a button defined like this: `<button class="marker">`.

## Addendum: 2015-Jun-24

### CSS (`<head>` tag)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"> </script>

<style>
    .btn_styling {
        text-align: center;
        width: 32px;
        margin: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 3px; 

       /* add a background image to the div 
          to make the div look like a button */ 
       /* background-image: url('...')  */
    }
    .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

HTML (.aspx)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="width: 400px;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      DataKeyNames="user_id"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="user_name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="divButton" runat="server" class="btn_styling dialog-marker" title="This could also have been a <button> element or maybe an <img> element...anything really">X</div>
            <div style="display: none;">
              <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="add_edit_date" HeaderText="Date Added" SortExpression="add_edit_date" DataFormatString='{0:dd-MMMM, yyyy}'/>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="add_edit_by" HeaderText="Added By" SortExpression="add_edit_by" />
                </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT email, add_edit_date, add_edit_by FROM tbl_users WHERE (user_id = @user_id)">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      <RowStyle BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT top 10 user_id, user_name from tbl_users">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </div>
  <div id="dialogContainer">
  </div>
</form>
```

### Code Behind (VB):

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim gv2 As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("GridView2"), GridView)
    Dim sds As SqlDataSource = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource2"), SqlDataSource)

    sds.SelectParameters("user_id").DefaultValue = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value
    gv2.DataBind()
  End If
End Sub
```

### jQuery to implement Dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialogOptions = {
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "#dialogContainer",
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        title: "Dialog Title",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    };

    $( function() {
        $( ".dialog-marker" ).on( "click", function() {
            var d = $( this ).next( "div" ).first().dialog( dialogOptions );
            d.dialog( "open" );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: Let me make it more clear, I need to bind the data in  2nd Gridview and display this Gridview2 in Jquery dialog .This data will be binded and displayed in dialog from on the click event of linkbutton inside Gridview1.

Comment: see addendum to my post

Comment: i tried to bind data on row data bound but it is still not displaying data in second gridview while pop is displaying

Comment: it won't happen _while_ it's in the popup.  It will/should happen during `GridView1`'s Databind().  You need to make sure you call `GridView2.Databind()` after you set the DataSource2 parameter.  Remember, all this happens during the GridView1 RowDatabound event.

Comment: And, if you haven't done so already, you need to style Gridview2 to be `display : none;`

Comment: can you make it for me from above code i tried it but it fails,still data is not binded to gridview2.

Comment: I'll post an example as soon as I can.

Comment: Example posted. Pardon the VB, but you should be able to convert it easily enough.

Comment: First of Thank You So Much !!!  and a little bit difficulty is that after displaying the record in pop the link gets disable and not opens the records again.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that while the popup is on display you cannot select another popup link.  such is the nature of a modal dialog.  But, that said, you can define the dialog as non modal, but you have to write the code to close the existing popup before opening the new one, otherwise they will overlay one another.

Comment: The link which displayed the data once  that goes disable and do not work again pelase modify the jquery code so that all links can work contineously when they are clicked.

Comment: @MurlidharThakur: I told you what you needed to do. I've given you 2 methods.  And now I've given you a real _working_ example. If you cannot figure it out from here...I don't know what else to do for you.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience But link do not work after working once.I tried to figure it out but i m not good in JavaScript so i got stuck again, Please Help me  Thanks a lot for the previous solutions. I deeply appreciate your efforts.  Thanks

Comment: But still didn't find the answer.Please help me.